# How to view Encrypted Application Data in Wireshark

Tags: ssl, https, wireshark

[image: screenshot of wireshark]

I have written an Android app to get JSON data via HTTPS and I want to use Wireshark to capture the data.

How can I view the Encrypted Application Data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent a loooong time to research it but it doesn't work. I use another tool to do that: Fiddler, [it's here](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), works well.

Comment: Fiddler worked for me! The Wireshark/SSLKEYLOGFILE worked for my browser-based traffic, but not on encrypted application data from other apps. Setting up decryption in Fiddler was more user-friendly, but setting up filtering had a learning curve since I was used to Wireshark/Microsoft Network Monitor.

Answer (score 3):

## Using a Key Log File

Wireshark can decrypt TLS data if you provide a file containing the master secret that's exchanged during a TLS connection.

Define the location of the log file using an environment variable:

```
export SSLKEYLOGFILE=~/.ssl-key.log
```

You can make this permanent by putting that line into your `.bashrc` or `bash_profile` but keeping those secrets lying around poses a security risk.

Then, point Wireshark to that file:

1. Go to preferences (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>) → Protocols → TLS (no need to scroll all the way down, you can type "TLS")
2. Enter the path of the log file in "(Pre)-Master-Secret log filename"

[image: Wireshark TLS preferences with (Pre)-Master-Secret log filename]

Start capturing packets with Wireshark, create some TLS traffic (with `curl` for example), and inspect the decrypted data:

[image: Wireshark packets with decrypted data]

Your `SSLKEYLOGFILE` will contain lines like these:

```
CLIENT_RANDOM c1299911e65097c367c0124fb97548f81b618cbdc9c270c10a350c4fd39f3eb6 0d7523a42610316250b7a72fe2881daa6aff1bedf5955c64a747fc43bd93cbf1bf3650eeabb8f47b350feaedd7209952
```

Here are some resources regarding TLS in Wireshark:

- [Wireshark wiki on TLS](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/TLS#using-the-pre-master-secret)
- [Article on decrypting TLS traffic with Wireshark](https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/decrypt-ssl-with-wireshark/)

---

The Wireshark version in this answer is 3.4.6 running on Arch Linux 5.12.9.

Comment: Where do you add the key file. How it just get decrypted?

Comment: @StanPeng: You define the location of the key log file with the environment variable `SSLKEYLOGFILE`. I chose the destination `~/.ssl-key.log` by running `export SSLKEYLOGFILE=~/.ssl-key.log` in Bash. Then I used Wireshark's settings as shown in the answer to tell Wireshark that the key log file will be at `~/.ssl-key.log`. Finally, if you use an application like `curl` that knows about `SSLKEYLOGFILE`, you'll get a file at `~/.ssl-key.log`. Wireshark will read it and use it to decrypt the traffic.