# Wireshark - reading encrypted data

Tags: encryption, wireshark, sniffing

I'm trying to learn how to use Wireshark properly and I'm wondering if Wireshark can read encrypted data it captures when sniffing? If so, how do I initiate this?

Comment: See also this question: [How to view Encrypted Application Data in Wireshark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456934/how-to-view-encrypted-application-data-in-wireshark/68095202)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wireshark supports decrypting SSL/TLS sessions if you provide it the private key the server uses to do key exchange. <s>If if a cipher suite is chosen that uses ephemeral keys, you will not be able to decrypt data.</s> **UPDATE:** Some TLS libraries can now dump per session key exchange secrets to a file for debugging. Wireshark can use that to decrypt the relevant TLS sessions even if ephemeral keys are used.

You can read more about this capability on the [Wireshark wiki for SSL](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/TLS).

See also this linked answer for [How to view Encrypted Application Data in Wireshark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68095202/260633)

Comment: Current versions of Wireshark allow decrypting TLS data using a key log file that contains the master secret exchanged during a TLS connection. See [this part of the Wireshark wiki](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/TLS#using-the-pre-master-secret). I've also written a short how-to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456934/how-to-view-encrypted-application-data-in-wireshark/68095202#68095202).

Comment: @MatthiasBraun thanks for the comment and updated wiki link. I updated the answer to help any future users who find this.

Answer (score 2):

Wireshark can dissect some types of encrypted data, in some circumstances; this includes SSL/TLS sessions, as per Dev's answer, and also includes WEP and WPA/WPA2 PSK 802.11 traffic, if you have the network password and, in the case of WPA/WPA2, the initial EAPOL handshake.  For that, see [the Wireshark Wiki's "How to Decrypt 802.11" page](http://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11).