# Wireshark Decryption of TLS V1.2

Tags: ssl, encryption, wireshark, tls1.2

I have traffic between clients (which send XML over HTTPS) to my IIS.

I tried to decrypt the traffic using Wireshark and the following settings:

Adding the private key:
[image: Wireshark preferences, TLS. RSA keys list]

But even after setting this, I can't see the decrypted data:

[image: Wireshark packets]

Should I change any other settings to see the original data?

Comment: If you control the client whose traffic you're interested in, you can use a key log file to decrypt the traffic with Wireshark. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456934/how-to-view-encrypted-application-data-in-wireshark#68095202) for instructions.

Answer (score 5):

There is strong possibility that a **Diffie-Hellman** (DH) key exchange is being used here. In that case Wireshark cannot decipher SSL/TLs with a private key. You can check for this in the handshake packet.

From the [Docs](https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS):

> The RSA private key file can only be used in the following
> circumstances:
>
> - The cipher suite selected by the server is not using (EC)**DHE**.
> - The protocol version is SSLv3, (D)TLS 1.0-1.2. It does not work with    **TLS 1.3**.
> - The private key matches the server certificate. It does not work with    the **client certificate**, nor the Certificate Authority (CA)
>   certificate.
> - The session has not been resumed. The handshake must include the    **ClientKeyExchange** handshake message.

Comment: Can you share what you see if you double click the fifth packet in that sequence ?

Comment: i see it now in the client key exchange,
is there any other way to sniff and decrypt the traffic?

Comment: You might be able to use a pre-master secret key, but this requires a browser client.  Here is a good walkthrough:  https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/decrypt-ssl-with-wireshark/  .

Comment: @developerlearn999: Just read the link provided in the answer. It tells you your options. Scroll down to "TLS Decryption"

Comment: The easiest (or perhaps hardest) thing to do is configure your client to only send RSA ciphersuites and hope that the server will choose one.

Comment: @developerlearn999: It is entirely dependent on the client, e.g. [this](https://superuser.com/questions/784765/how-to-change-the-cipher-suites-list-in-chrome-internet-explorer) question. You also need a server that will allow RSA ciphersuites. If you to focus on one, I would choose `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` since it's the one ciphersuite mandated in TLS 1.2.